# How to change user's app settings on developers facebook profile?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Basically what I want to achieve is if user checks chechbox saying: "Allow app to change your  `App’s Canvas URL` and `Secure Canvas URL` within `Facebook` in order to work properly" to change these two fields on user's developer's facebook account. I haven't tried anything because I've researched a lot on `Facebook Developers` documentation and haven't find anything that suits my problem. I assume I'll need some of the permisssions to do this, but I don't know which. Samples of code would be very appreciated.

Comment: what do you want and what you have tried?

Comment: Have you read my question?

Comment: To get your question right, you basically want to change a (Secure) Canvas URL of an app?

Comment: @Dees040, that is exactly what I want to change, and thanks a lot for your answer. As soon as I try it i will let you know if it works or not and honor you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research for you as well.

What you want to acomplish is possible. If found the right documentation on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application

You first need to have the Application ID and the app access token. HTTP example:

```
POST /v2.5/{application-id}?canvas_url={url}&secure_canvas_url={url} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

I hope you can figure something out. Goodluck!

Comment: hey Dees, i tried like so: `$.post('/v2.5/'+appSec,{canvas_url:'https://apps.facebook.com/ognjen', secure_canvas_url:'https://renotifier.com/canvas/399/ognjen'});` but it doesn't work.. Am I missing something?